# Where located /etc/ldap.conf in CentOS 6.3?

Tags: centos, ldap, centos6

Where I can find `/etc/ldap.conf` file to configure system authentication through `LDAP` in CentOS 6.3?

Comment: Probably at /etc/ldap.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CentOS 6, `/etc/ldap.conf` was replaced with `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`.  At a minimum, you also need to run the `nslcd` service and update `/etc/nslcd.conf`.

Red Hat recommends using `SSSD`, in their Deployment Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below:

> find / -name ldap.conf -print

Comment: ok, I found it. But I want to use IBM Tivoli directory server, not OpenLDAP as LDAP-provider.  And in IBM documentation written that it must be inside root of `/etc`\

Comment: @MyTitle, you can create a link in /etc to the file you found.

Comment: Different linux distributions have different directory structures, and also different versions of ldap may have different directory structures. But i dont think it will make big difference, just use the file you already found.